# Distribute GA Algorithm with OpenMPI

Tags: c++, algorithm, genetic-algorithm, openmpi

I'm new working with OpenMPI... I built a GA algorithm (c++) to solve an n-th variable equation and now I am trying to improve its performance by using OpenMPI parallelization.

The code structure goes as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i=1;
    int print=0;
    int fitness_check;

    if ( argc < 2 ) print=1; 


    //initialize rand parameter
    srand(time(0));
    //start counting clock
    auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    //start GA
    population *pop=new population();
    pop->calcPopFitness();
    pop->popSort();

    fitness_check=pop->getElement(0).getFitness();
    while(pop->getElement(0).getFitness()!=0){
        pop->evolvePop();

        pop->calcPopFitness();

        pop->popSort();


        if(fitness_check<(pop->getElement(0).getFitness())){
            cout<<"Error in elitism\n";
            cout<<"---------------------------\nPrinting after sort...\n";
            pop->printPopulation();
            cout<<"\n-------------------------------------------\n";
            exit(1);
        }else{
            if(fitness_check>(pop->getElement(0).getFitness()))
                fitness_check=(pop->getElement(0).getFitness());
        }
        if(print==1)cout<<"\nBest string fit in ("+to_string(i)+") iteration: "+string(pop->getElement(0).getString())+"\n";
        i++;
    }
    if(print==1)cout<<"\nGA algorithms work!\n";
    //end of GA algorithm and stop counting time
    auto end_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto time = end_time - start_time;
    if(print==1)std::cout << "It took " <<
    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(time).count() << " milliseconds to run.\n";
    writeFile(pop->getElement(0).getValues(), to_string(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(time).count()));
    pop->cleanup();
    delete pop;
    return 0;
}
```

My classes are:

```
class chromossome{
    private:
        int * values;


    public:
        unsigned int fitness;
        //constructor
        chromossome();
        chromossome(int *vector);
        void deleteVector();

        bool operator<(const chromossome& other) const {
            return fitness < other.fitness;
        }
        unsigned int getFitness();
        int* getValues();
        void calcFitness();
        void setGene(int i, int gene);
        int getGene(int i);
        //int constgetGene(int i) const;
        void mutate();
        string getString() const;
};
```

and

```
class population{
    private:
        int population_size;
        vector<chromossome> ChromoPopulation;
    public:
        population();
        population(bool newIteration);
        int getSize();
        void printPopulation();
        void removeChromossome();
        chromossome getElement(int position);
        void calcPopFitness();
        void popSort();
        void addChromossome(chromossome individual);
        chromossome *tournamentSelection();
        chromossome* crossover(chromossome a, chromossome b);
        void mutate();
        chromossome * cloneChromossome(chromossome c);
        vector<chromossome> getList();
        void evolvePop();
        void cleanup();
};
```

As a first approach I'm just trying to distribute the the fitness function, so that each process computes the fitness of a part of the population. I thought this can be achieved by either passing indexes to perform the computations in a range (this would require that every process has access to the same population) or by sending the population elements.

```
void population::calcPopFitness(){
    for_each(ChromoPopulation.begin(), ChromoPopulation.end(), [=]( chromossome & n)
        {n.calcFitness();});
    return;
}

void chromossome::calcFitness(){
    int result=0;
    for(int i=0; i<NUMBERVARIABLES; i++){
        result+=values[i]*(i+1);
    }
    result-=1024;
    fitness=result;
    return;
}
```

My goal is to then perform this computations with large populations and large number of variables.

Can someone tell me what is the best approach and if possible give me some code examples? I've been struggling with this for a week and did not make any progress so far in this matter...

Thanks in advance... any help is a huge help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at our implementation of a Genetic Programming variant using MPI:

https://github.com/mihaioltean/evolve-tsp-heuristics/tree/master/train/mpi

Our purpose is to train heuristics for the TSP problem, but this takes a lot of time, so we decided to use MPI to run on multiple computers. We also used threads, inside the same processor, to reduce the MPI overhead.

We have divided our (super)population into multiple populations and at the end of each generation we exchange some individuals between populations (see the MPI_Send/Recv part).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll check the code out and let you know if it solved my issue as soon as possible!

Comment: Thanks! This approach for individuals passing worked for me!